# Google Drive: The file size is null

Tags: google-drive-api

when I try to get the file size by getFileSize() on Google Drive the result is null. I know that the result can be null when the file in not stored on Drive but the file is stored on Drive (downloadUrl is different from null).

```
    Drive lService = new Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), lCredential).setApplicationName("TODO").build();
    FileList files = lService.files().list().execute();

    List<FileDTO> lResult = new ArrayList<FileDTO>();
    for (File lFile : files.getItems()) {
        DriveFileDTO lFileDTO = new DriveFileDTO();
        lFileDTO.setName(lFile.getTitle());
        lFileDTO.setMimeType(lFile.getMimeType());
        lFileDTO.setSize(lFile.getFileSize()); // <-- FileSize = NULL

        lFileDTO.setUrl(lFile.getDownloadUrl());

        lResult.add(lFileDTO);
    }
```

Can you help me?

Thanks!
aGO!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call `getHeaders().GetContentLength()` on the HttpResponse Class (code assumes `myurl` is your url):

```
HttpResponse resp = service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(myurl)).execute();
Log.v("abc","file size is : " + resp.getHeaders().getContentLength());
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  The question asks for file.size.  The request is for a list of files, hence there are many file sizes, not just one. If this returns a value, it not the size of any file, but rather the size of the list being returned.

Answer (score 1):

A default request for a file list from Google Drive will include file size, but only for files where the file size is not implicitly null.  For example, folders and Google spreadsheets (which are simply links) will be null.

This can be verified with the Drive API exlporer.  Simply request filesize and mimtype in the fields editor.  A key-value pair will not be included in the response for the file types mentioned, even though a filesize was requested -- yet will be returned for other types.

Answer (score 0):

Please try reproducing the issue with the OAuth 2.0 Playground:

https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground

By using the OAuth Playground we can send raw requests and check whether there's an issue in the API.
I tried reproducing it myself and it worked correctly.

Comment: Thank you Cloudio for your help. If I use OAuth playground I can see the file size. If I do the same action by Google Drive API the size is NULL

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the Java client library? Does the issue only happen with a single file? If so, can you share one of the affected files? I still can't reproduce it with my test accounts.

Comment: After the test by OAuth playground it's working...I can't explain it. Now I'm using the latest java client library. If I will reproduce the issue I will write it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the problem of getting file size from Google Drive API.
But then I found a solution.
Add a ".setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, createdTime, modifiedTime, size, kind)")" field to the request.
Here you need to list the fields to which you want to access.

```
    FileList result = mDrive
            .files()
            .list()
            .setQ("parents = 'MY_FODER'")
            .setSpaces("drive")
            .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, createdTime, modifiedTime, size, kind)")
            .execute();
```

Also, when creating the Drive, add a Scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"

```
    GoogleAccountCredential credential =
            GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    mContext,
                    Arrays.asList(
                            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
                            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly",
                            Scopes.EMAIL));
    credential.setSelectedAccount(mAccount.getAccount());

    mDrive = new Drive.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new GsonFactory(),
                    credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Android-client")
                    .build();
```