# How to get the content length(aka file size) from the MediaHttpDownloader? drive file.getSize() always return null

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-client

I want to download a file from Gdrive. So I m using drive API v3 (java).

here the code snippet.

```
Drive.Files.Get request = driveService.files().get(fileId);
// Get the file metadata
File downloadFile = request.execute();
Long fileSize = downloadFile.getSize(); // always returns null.

OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);

request.getMediaHttpDownloader().setProgressListener(
                            new DriveDownloadProgressListener(messageQueue));
request.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
```

here downloadFile.getSize() always returns null.
Is there any way to get the file size from the MediaHttpDownloader?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Drive: The file size is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12747239/google-drive-the-file-size-is-null)

Comment: Nope.I checked already.

Comment: Did the correct size get displayed when using the API Explorer on the Google-API site?

Comment: Yes , I tried get request with field 'size'. displayed the correct size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to add required fields myself in the request.

like this

```
Drive.Files.Get request = driveService.files().get(fileId).setFields("size");
File file = request.execute(); // contains only size field.Other fields will be empty
```

then execute and get the expected response(It only send fields setted by yourself)

For example, if you need name and size of the file.

```
Drive.Files.Get request = driveService.files().get(fileId).setFields("name,size"); // name and size
File file = request.execute(); // contains only name and size field.Other fields will be empty(respective get methods will return null only)
```

Comment: If you solved your problem, make sure to mark the answer that helped with "correct answer"!

Comment: After 2 days, I will